# shell script taking input from python program

Tags: python, shell, input

I have a shell script which runs a python program which has its own parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
python blah.py var1 var2
./run key
```

I need to find a way to retrieve the contents of key from the python program. I have tried just making the python program return the value, and then doing :

```
key=python blah.py var1 var2
```

in my shell script, but that didn't work because it stated key was "outside the function".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
key=`python blah.py var1 var2`
./run $key
```

Comment: this just sets key equal to python

Comment: Really?? Hope you are not using single quote, however refer here if still a problem http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/390664-how-can-i-redirect-stdout-variable.html

Comment: You're right, but I guess there's something wrong with my logic here. I can't return a variable from that python file, because returning the variable from main states makes it state  that "return" is outside the function. Any suggestions?

Comment: just print it....using print(blah blah blah)[python>3.0] or print blah blah blah [python<3.0] :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
./run $( python blah.py var1 var2 )
```

The `$(  )` syntax opens a subshell, and runs the command. The stdout output is then dumped in its place

Answer (score 0):

One liner demo:
(ok, so it's two lines)

```
$ key=`python -c 'print "hi"'`
$ echo $key
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to modifying the python script to output the value of the `key` variable is to modify the python script to call the `run` program

```
import subprocess
# ... calculations, and set the "key" variable ...
subprocess.call(["./run", key])
```