# parsing stdout in shell script

Tags: python, shell, stdout

Continuation of my initial question:

[shell script taking input from python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204857/shell-script-taking-input-from-python-program)

So I have standard output from my python program being stored in a variable in my shell script. Now, I have to parse this output so that I can take a substring of the last 22 characters. These are the only ones that matter to me. Unfortunately there's no way to really identify these last characters ("keyword=", etc.), meaning I have to do this completely by their position

Comment: would be helpful to show some sample output

Answer (score 1):

If you need the last N characters of a string, you can use a simple slice:

```
>>> v="this is the stdout from my shell command stored in a variable"
>>> v[-22:]
'd stored in a variable'
```

The last 22 chars are returned.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, but the 22 chars at the end are to be kept, so `v[-22:]` is more appropriate

Comment: @WilliamPursell you're right, I misread the question.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `bash`, you can use substring expansion:

```
key=$(python ...)   # From  your previous question

suffix=${key: -22}  # The space between : and - is important
```